# Make Visual Studio Code open files in the already open project window?

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, visual-studio-code

I build my project on the terminal using make. When I encounter some compile errors, the output indicates in which files there is an error. I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the file names to open them (a feature of iTerm). However, this makes Visual Studio Code open a new window with that single file, instead of navigating to that file in the already open project window. Is there a way to change this?

There is an option `window.openFilesInNewWindow`, but that only works for files opened within VS Code, not from Finder or other apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VSCode accepts -r or --reuse-window as a parameter to force opening a file in the active project window.
If you can configure your iTerm feature and add this parameter, it should work as expected.

Reference : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics

Comment: The code basics page doesn't discuss --reuse-window, at least not now. But it is mentioned on the command line options page. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line